# Connecting to MariaDB with nodejs over ssl with clear text password

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am trying to connect to mariadb instance over ssl,

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    debug: true,
    port: '3306',
    host: "host",
    ssl: {
        "ca": ca
    }
});

conn.connect();
```

the ca is an array of cerificates. I am getting the following error.

```
Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client
```

I am able to connect to the db using python with mysql.connector.

After setting it on debug mode, I can see the client is trying to use mysql_native_password authentication. I need to use mysql_clear_password.

Comment: Have you tried [`mysql2`](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)?

Comment: yes, gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your server supports plugin based auth and auth switch request, you can try following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    debug: true,
    port: '3306',
    host: "host",
    ssl: {
        "ca": ca
    },
    authSwitchHandler: (data, cb) => {
      if (data.pluginName === 'mysql_clear_password') {
      // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/clear-text-authentication.html
      var password = 'password\0';
      var buffer = Buffer.from(password);
      cb(null, buffer);
    }
  });
```

unfortunately initial auth type is always `mysql_native` with node-mysql2 ( I hope to fix this soon ), so you need both auth_plugin and auth_switch support enabled on server

Edit: Syntax