# Stuck on talking to RDS/Aurora from node

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

Thought I'd ask this as my team and I are banging our heads against this.

We are attempting to setup Aurora/RDS (Mysql) access via IAM roles and node.

We've tried a number of different approaches, and two particular node/mysql libraries (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql and https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2).

We're able to use the RDS Signer to generate an appropriate token, and we get a valid one back.

We then try to connect to the DB as shown below.  We've tried with a number of different approaches from both of the above libraries - it seems that we need to enable mysql clear password (as per https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/438#issuecomment-255343793)

Our code (give or take) is:

```
var AWS = require('AWS-SDK');
AWS.config.update({ "accessKeyId": "{valid access key}", "secretAccessKey": "{valid secret access key}", "region": "eu-west-1" });

var mysql = require('mysql2');

var signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
    credentials: new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'}),
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    hostname: '{rds database host}',
    port: 3306,
    username: '{rds database username}'
  });

  signer.getAuthToken({}, function(err, token){
    console.log(token);

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : '{rds database host}',
        user     : '{rds database username}',
        password : token,
        port     : 3306,
        database: '{rds database}'
        ,authSwitchHandler: function ({pluginName, pluginData}, cb) {
          if (pluginName === 'mysql_clear_password') {
            // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/clear-text-authentication.html
            var password = dbConf.password + '\0';
            var buffer = Buffer.from(password);
            cb(null, buffer);
          } else {
            const err = new Error(`Unknown AuthSwitchRequest plugin name ${pluginName}`);
            err.fatal = true;
            cb(err);
          }
        }
      });

      connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
          return;
        }

        console.log('Connected to database.');
      });

      connection.end();
});
```

We get:

```
Database connection failed: Error: Access denied for user '{dbuser}'@'{ip address}' (using password: YES)
at Packet.asError (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:703:13)
at ClientHandshake.Command.execute (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:28:22)
at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:515:28)
at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:16)
at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:77:14)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Terry.Brown\Desktop\iam-rds-auth\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:102:29)
at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:237:11)
```

I feel like there's a step we're missing, but I have no idea what it is.  Has anyone solved the aurora/rds / iam / node dance and can give any pointers?

Thanks :)

Comment: Also added ',ssl: "Amazon RDS"' which helped, and certainly got us into the authSwitchHandler, but still getting a access denied.

Comment: *"and we get a valid one back"*  Just checking: how are you determining that it is "valid?"

Comment: we've generated a token with both the AWS cli tools, and via code, and the structure and semantics in the token look the same.  I guess 'valid' is probably the more appropriate term - it looks syntactically correct - whether it is valid and working, we obviously don't know yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made it work from the command-line?  I struggled with that, until someone found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710284/iam-database-authentication-how-to-use-cli-generated-token).

Download https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem and add `--ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` to your command line.

Frustrating, as that's not in the AWS walkthrough (not yet at least, our TAM is going to get it put there).

If that works on the command-line, then try adding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448563/connecting-to-mariadb-with-nodejs-over-ssl-with-clear-text-password) to your connection config object:

```
   ssl: {
      ca: fs.readFileSync("/tmp/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem")
   },
```

That should get you further.

Comment: Hey together, I'm not getting it to work either. Can you provide a full example? Do you use sequelice?